# Create an upload form, select a folder and get a specific file in folder

Tags: html, cgi

To upload a single file, it is very simple to use this HTML script:
    `<p> <input type="file" name="input.txt" />`
In this question, my task is to select a folder and then get the `input.txt` inside that folder. The server will response whether input.txt is available or not and  to upload it to web server.

Is there any way to select a folder instead selecting a file in the input form. 
Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to change: `<p> <input type="folder" name="input.txt" />`but it seems I need to type the folder path myself instead of the dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use HTML to select folder.
However, you can use Java applet, Flash  or other similar technologies in order to show folder selection dialog in your page.

Comment: Thanks, I find a way to use activeX object to insert in the html page : http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5201